# Uniqueness of categorical products

Tags: category-theory, products

I'm currently studying category theory out of [Awodey's excellent online book](http://angg.twu.net/MINICATS/awodey__category_theory.pdf), but I'm having trouble seeing that the mapping between two product objects is necessarily an iso.

If $P,p_0:P\rightarrow A,p_1:P\rightarrow B$ and $X,x_0:X\rightarrow A,x_1:X\rightarrow B$ are product diagrams for $A$ and $B$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$, then we obtain unique arrows $u_0:X\rightarrow P$ and $u_1:P\rightarrow X$ which yield the identities $$x_0=p_0\circ u_0,$$ $$p_0=x_0\circ u_1,$$ which we can then substitute into each other to obtain $$x_0=x_0\circ u_1\circ u_0,$$ $$p_0=p_0\circ u_0\circ u_1.$$ At this stage the author asserts that these identities, together with the identities $$x_0=x_0\circ1_X,$$ $$p_0=p_0\circ1_P$$ and the uniqueness condition on $u_0$ and $u_1$ yield the desired equalities $u_0\circ u_1=1_P$ and $u_1\circ u_0=1_X$, but I can't quite see it.

If there is some other arrow $u_2:P\rightarrow X$ such that $u_0\circ u_2=1_P$ then I agree we would have a contradiction, since we then have $$p_0=p_0\circ1_P=p_0\circ u_0\circ u_2=x_0\circ u_2$$ and $u_1$ is unique with this property, but is the existence of $u_2$ necessary if $u_0\circ u_1\neq1_P$? Could the identity not hold and there be no such $u_2$?

(There are of course corresponding identities for $p_1$ and $x_1$, but they lead me to the same question.)

Comment: Don't forget there is a corresponding pair of identities involving $x_1$ and $p_1$. (Incidentally, you may need to change your labeling of the maps.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $P, p_0,p_1$ is a product diagram, any pair of arrows $C\to A, C\to B$ leads through it by a *unique* $C\to P$.

Now, for the pair $(x_0,x_1)$ this unique arrow is $u_0:X\to P$, and for the pair $(p_0,p_1)$, it is certainly $1_P$. But, taking the compositions, also $u_0\circ u_1:P\to P$ leads $(p_0,p_1)$ through itself. 
This means, by uniqueness, $u_0\circ u_1=1_P$.

Comment: Excellent, I hadn't thought of pulling a product diagram down over itself using the identity. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to express the uniqueness property connected with products.

If $P$ serves as product of $A$ and $B$ with projections $p_0:P\to A$ and $p_1:P\to B$ then pair $(p_0,p_1)$ is a so-called **monosource** which means that on base of the equalities: $$p_0\circ f=p_0\circ g\text{ and }p_1\circ f=p_1\circ g$$ you are allowed to conclude that: $$f=g$$

---

In your case we have: $$p_0\circ u_0\circ u_1=p_0\circ\mathsf{id}_P\text{ and }p_1\circ u_0\circ u_1=p_1\circ\mathsf{id}_P$$ so you are allowed to conclude that: $$u_0\circ u_1=\mathsf{id}_P$$

Similarly it can be found that: $$u_1\circ u_0=\mathsf{id}_X$$
This together proves that $u_0$ and $u_1$ are isomorphisms and are inverses of eachother.